# Differentiate values inside Table using Dynamic

Tags: dynamic

I would have thought that the following code would let each indexed variable take its value from the `SetterBar`. Instead, all the `SetterBar`s take the same value, as the image illustrates. Essentially all the `SetterBar`s set the value of `var[j]` instead of each setting the value of variables `var[1]`, `var[2]`, etc. How can I get Mathematica to evaluate the indices when assigning values using the `SetterBar`s inside the `Table`?

```
TableForm[
 Table[{"Variable " <> ToString[var[j]], 
   SetterBar[
    Dynamic@var[j], {0 -> "negative", 1 -> "positive", 
     2 -> "ignore"}]}, {j, 5}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a scoping issue. You can use [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html) to get the expected behavior.

```
Column[{
  TableForm[
   Table[With[{j = j}, {"Variable " <> ToString[var[j]], 
      SetterBar[Dynamic@var[j], {0 -> "negative", 1 -> "positive", 2 -> "ignore"}]}], 
    {j, 5}]],
  Table[With[{j = j}, Dynamic@var[j]], {j, 5}]}
 ]
```

> [image: Out]

Comment: Fabulous, many thanks. Could you please explain Ma's scoping principles? Is there a logic of which commands prevent the evaluation of their contents and which do not?

Comment: @NicholasG "Table effectively uses Block to localize values or variables." [[`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html?q=Table)]

Comment: @NicholasG [Scoping Constructs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ScopingConstructs.html)

Comment: Why does the variable name get substituted by its value when I reevaluate this? `TableForm[
 Table[{"Variable " <> ToString[var[j]], 
   With[{j = j}, 
    SetterBar[
     Dynamic@var[j], {0 -> "liberal", 1 -> "conservative", 
      2 -> "ignore"}]]}, {j, 5}]]`

Comment: @NicholasG Presumably because it already has a value. Evaluate `Clear[var]` and then your input again.

Comment: @NicholasG Or use `ToString[Unevaluated@var[j]]` instead.